# Sorting categories of CategoryAxis javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing a javafx programme in which i need to show a LineChart with a CategoryAxis as x axis. I would like to make the different categories on the axis appear in a certain order. Is there any way to achieve this? Right now the order of the categories on my CategoryAxis depends on which order i enter the data.

Thanks!

Comment: Since JavaFX 8u40 maybe https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/LineChart.SortingPolicy.html will help you.